# Handling refresh with a form having POST method

Tags: javascript, html

I have one html page contains form with `POST` method.

When i submit the form, it shows some details. 

But when i am using a refresh function, it says problem with the document. 

Refresh routine is handled like this : `document.location = window.location`

I know it won't work when i use `POST` method, `window.location` will only have the form action value without parameters. 

So is there any way to handle refresh or to retain the parameters thrown from ?

So basically i want to retrieve query string thrown by POST method

Comment: You migt want to save the current URL to a variable when the page is loaded. When you want to *refresh*, use that variable instead of from `window.location`.

Comment: I am not able to get field values